# Is it possible for a Moderator to edit multiple user comments for privacy reasons?

Tags: support, comments, moderators, moderator-tools

A user asked [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57500/told-ive-been-asking-too-many-questions-and-put-on-review) and then realized they had used their real name and wanted to change that. They were instructed how to change their user name here but several of the comments seem to still have **@User'sRealName** in the text so the privacy issue still stands. Can this be fixed by a Moderator or is that outside of their abilities?

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:** Yes, we can!

If there is something like this, then just a mod flag is enough to notify us and we can action it.  It is a manual process for us to change each one, or we can simply purge comments.

I'll troll through the comments on that thread, and depending on how many instances I find I will either edit them out or just get rid of them :)

[Edit]

Done.  If I've missed any, just flag them and we'll fix them :)

Comment: Thank you Jane S.